# Trigonometry equation simplification

Tags: trigonometry

So, I've been given the trig equation: $$\csc^2x - \cot 2x = 1$$ Using the identity and rearranging $$\cot^22x + 1 = \csc^22x$$ the equation simplifies to $$\cot^22x - \cot2x = 0$$ factoring out $\cot 2x$ $$ \cot 2x (\cot 2x -1) = 0$$ I've bee told to solve $\forall x | 0\leq x\leq180$

So... $$ \cot 2x = 0 $$or$$ \cot 2x = 1 $$

$$ \frac{1}{\tan2x} = 0 \Rightarrow 1 = 0 \times \tan 2x $$ therefore no solutions.

$$ \cot 2x = 1 \Rightarrow \tan 2x = 1 $$ $$ x\in\{22.5,112.5\}$$

Both of my solutions were correct, but I lost marks since apparently there are two extra solutions! 45 & 135 degrees. I don't know where I went wrong in my workings and was wondering if someone could tell me what I did wrong.

-Thanks

Comment: Notice that $$\cot(x)=0 \iff \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=0\iff \cos(x)=0\iff x=90+180k$$

Answer (score 1):

cot 2x = 0

cot 2x = cot 90

**As cot 90 = 0**

2x = 90

x = 45

So $ x\in\{45,135\}$